# How to concatenate string in select clause of a google sheet query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

How can I concatenate a string in a select clause of google sheet query function ?

ex: `=QUERY(DATAS!B:F; "SELECT B,C,D,'=image('&E&')',F WHERE upper(F) "&J4&" upper('"&N4&"') LIMIT 50";1)`

Here I want to get E column as `=image(E)` in the sheet.

Anyone with an idea ?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(DATAS!B:F; "select B,C,D where upper(F) "&J4&" upper('"&N4&"') limit 50"; 1), 
         IMAGE(QUERY(DATAS!B:F; "select E where upper(F) "&J4&" upper('"&N4&"') limit 50"; 1)),
               QUERY(DATAS!B:F; "select F where upper(F) "&J4&" upper('"&N4&"') limit 50"; 1)})
```